# How to change when the 'low stock' message appears

Tags: magento-1.9, product, stock

I'm currently adding products to a new Magento website. We only stock small many items. When I put 3 or less items in the product inventory (manage products) the *Low Stock* message show on the item image at the front end. How can I stop this?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps

1. Go to `admin->Configuration->Catalog(from left menu)->Inventory->Product Stock Options->Notify for Quantity Below` add zero in **Notify for Quantity Below** field

see this:

[image]

2. Clear cache and check